# Why does getClass return a different value on a case class constructor parameter when queried from outside the case class?

Tags: scala, class, types, case-class

I'm new to Scala and I don't understand this:

```
scala> case class foo[T](value:T){println(value.getClass.toString)}
defined class foo

scala> val bar=foo(1)
class java.lang.Integer
bar: foo[Int] = foo(1)

scala> println(bar.value.getClass.toString)
int
```

Upon construction it returns 'class java.lang.Integer', when queried outside the case class it returns 'int'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is auto(un)boxing. The JVM requires `T` to be a subclass of `Object` to be used as a generic type parameter, so `value` is actually an `Integer`. 
Outside of the generic code, when compiler knows the concrete type of `value`, it unboxes it for you, so that it becomes `int`.

Note that it has nothing to do with case classes (or classes at all for that matter), it's just an artifact of how type parameters and value classes are implemented. Try this:

```
 def foo[T](value: T) = { println(value.getClass); value }
 println(foo(1).getClass)
```

This will print:

```
 class java.lang.Integer
 int
```

Comment: Yeah, to make it clear I would add that this has nothing to do with case classes but only genericity